# why did the arrows in my treeview turn to strange squares

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have an user control which has a treeview. This user control inherits from a base user control.
I was able to see the arrows in the treeview well till I changed the base control graphics.
From that point I started to see strange squares instead of the regular arrow in the treeview.
Is there any reason for this behavior?

Comment: Please add a small sample of code so we can better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was influenced by a style that was defined in the app.xaml.
The target type of the style was Border. 
Probably the type of the arrows in the treeview is some border, and the public border type in the app xaml caused those arrows to be changed.